# Where I can find all the files which were committed by an user to the gitosis repository on my server?

Tags: git, gitosis

I just installed gitosis on my server and I successfully 
 created a new repository.
 I can commit changes to git@IP:srv_repository.git but I don't know where I can find these files (with committed changes) on my server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *files* may not be directly visible on your server.  They've been committed to the home directory of the `git` user, somewhere inside the `repositories` directory.  These are all *bare* repositories; to see the actual files you'll have to clone the appropriate repository.  For example:

```
mkdir work
cd work
git clone ~/repositories/myrepo.git
```